# Welcome message with Ibot interface

Tags: botframework

I am using the Ibot interface, but the welcome message is sent twice.
I use the OnTurnAsync method, and it seems that doesn't do anything when I call the MembersAdded property.

To send the Welcome message i have this piece of code:

```
if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate && turnContext.Activity.MembersAdded.Count == 1)
        {

            userProfile.Welcome = true;


            var reply = turnContext.Activity.CreateReply();
            reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
            reply.Attachments.Add(getCard("Welcome"));

            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply);
        }
```

Comment: Which channel are you targeting? And this point has been often treated: if you really use this event, you should check the `memberAdded` field

Comment: I am using WebChat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things that could be going on with this.

1. MembersAdded is called for adding both the bot and the user. I'm guessing this is why it's being sent twice.

If you're using the newer ActivityHandler, you can use:

```cs
protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    foreach (var member in membersAdded)
    {
        if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
        {
            userProfile.Welcome = true;

            var reply = turnContext.Activity.CreateReply();
            reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
            reply.Attachments.Add(getCard("Welcome"));

            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply);
        }
    }
}
```

Or, if you're using the old activity handler:

```cs
public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
    {
        if (activity.MembersAdded != null)
        {
            foreach (var member in activity.MembersAdded)
            {
                if (member.Name != "Bot" && member.Name != null)
                {
                    userProfile.Welcome = true;

                    var reply = turnContext.Activity.CreateReply();
                    reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
                    reply.Attachments.Add(getCard("Welcome"));

                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [...]
```

2. WebChat doesn't automatically send a ConversationUpdate like Emulator does. [See this WebChat sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/15.d.backchannel-send-welcome-event) for how to send a welcome event.
3. You could always ensure it doesn't double-send by checking to see if `userProfile.Welcome != true`. [This sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/03.welcome-user) may help.

Comment: Thanks, I used my bot name and the userProfile.Welcome != true is no longer needed, although I had to put that "method" in the end of the OnTurnAsync otherwise it would not enter on ActivityTypes.Message.